# Run oracle query (SQL) every 30 seconds and once count equals 8 it should proceed further and finish the job

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks, dbms-scheduler

I was looking for a solution to my problem on the internet, however I could not find fit for purpose solution. Can some please help and guide me with some examples.

In Oracle em console I have a job that runs for at least for 1 hour and during the job running process it will update few tables in Oracle.

Basically I want SQL query to run every 1 minute and once count equals 8 it should stop and move ahead....

TABLE_NAME: TASK - This table will get updated during 1 hour processing

```
ID TYPE_ID VALUE
1  12      TEST1
2  13      TEST2
3  14      TEST3
4  15      TEST4
5  16      TEST5
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: "Basically I want SQL query to run every 1 minute and once count equals 8 it should stop and move ahead...." What SQL? Count of what? What if it never exactly equals 8 but goes above 8 (i.e. jumps from 7 to 9+)? What should it move ahead to do?

Comment: Hi Anthony, Count will be of ID and count will not exceed 8. I have some if blocks with jUnit assertions so I want to do assertions only when count reaches 8.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a job and schedule it using **DBMS_SCHEDULER**. All your logic could reside in a PL/SQL **procedure** and then **schedule** the procedure to execute at desired **intervals**.

For example,

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
  3      job_name        => 'test_job',
  4      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5      job_action      => 'BEGIN my_job_procedure; END;',
  6      start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  7      repeat_interval => 'freq=0; byminute=0; bysecond=30;',
  8      end_date        => NULL,
  9      enabled         => TRUE,
 10      comments        => 'Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.');
 11  END;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT JOB_NAME, ENABLED FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS where job_name ='TEST_JOB'
  2  /

JOB_NAME                 ENABL
--------------------     -----
TEST_JOB                 TRUE

SQL>
```

The above job would start per your **SYSTIMESTAMP**, and then execute the procedure `my_job_procedure` every **30 seconds**.

See more examples [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php).

Comment: Thank you Lalit. Actually this is part of the test so I won't be allowed to create a procedure..

Comment: @user3463885 No problem, create an anonymous PL/SQL block, thus you do not create any database object, you just execute the logic you want.